# Make variadic function which takes arbitary functors and returns a tuple of each return value of input functors

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

I want to make a function object which takes arbitrary function objects and returns a tuple which stores the return value of each function object.

To achieve this goal, I made a `class A`

```
class A
{
private:
    template <class Ret, class Func>
    auto impl(Ret ret, Func func) -> decltype(tuple_cat(ret, make_tuple(func())))
    {
        return tuple_cat(ret, make_tuple(func()));
    }

    template <class Ret, class First, class... Funcs>
    auto impl(Ret ret, First first, Funcs... funcs) 
    -> decltype(impl(tuple_cat(ret, make_tuple(first())), funcs...))
    {
    return impl(tuple_cat(ret, make_tuple(first())), funcs...);
    }

public:
    template <class Func>
    auto operator()(Func func) -> decltype(make_tuple(func()))
        {
        return make_tuple(func());
    }

    template <class First, class... Funcs>
    auto operator()(First first, Funcs... funcs)
     -> decltype(impl(make_tuple(first()),funcs...))
    {
        impl(make_tuple(first()),funcs...);
    }
};
```

And in the main function, I made three lambdas.

```
int main(){
    auto func1 = [](){ cout << 1 << endl; return 1;};
    auto func2 = [](){ cout << 2 << endl; return 2;};
    auto func3 = [](){ cout << 3 << endl; return 3;};

    A a;
    auto x = a(func1, func2);
    cout << "ans : " << get<0>(x) << get<1>(x) << endl; // I expect ans : 12
}
```

This code can be compiled by gcc 4.7.2. However, it doesn't work as I expected.
How should I modify this code?

Comment: _"However, it doesn't work as I expected."_ So how does it work?

Comment: I got some trash values. In my computer, I got `-2 1962460021`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're missing a `return` statement:

```
template <class First, class... Funcs>
auto operator()(First first, Funcs... funcs)
 -> decltype(impl(make_tuple(first()),funcs...))
{
    return impl(make_tuple(first()),funcs...);
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

Without it, your code has Undefined Behavior. Per Paragraph 6.6.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem is that you've a missing return statement as pointed out by other answer.

Anyway, I think you have done too much. This should work:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class First, class... Funcs>
    auto operator()(First first, Funcs... funcs) -> decltype((make_tuple(first(),funcs()...)))
    {
        return (make_tuple(first(),funcs()...));
    }
};

int main(){
    auto func1 = [](){ cout << 1 << endl; return 1;};
    auto func2 = [](){ cout << 2 << endl; return 2;};

    A a;
    auto x = a(func1, func2);
    cout << "ans : " << get<0>(x) << get<1>(x) << endl; // I expect ans : 12
}
```

[Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4495a718a494a626e57f5e915473c3dc)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just seen your code. It is almost the same as mfontanini's. So, I want to ask the same question above. Could you give me some reference regarding the line `make_tuple(first(),funcs()...)`?

Comment: @Sungmin: [Here is online doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) for `std::make_tuple`. Have a look at it, and understand the usage!

Answer (score 1):

@Andy's fix works, but you can do it *a lot* simpler than that, without implementing overloads nor helper functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Args>
auto tuple_from_funs(Args&&... args) -> std::tuple<decltype(args())...>{
    return std::make_tuple(args()...);
}

int f() { return 1; }
char g() { return '2'; }
std::string h() { return "jorge"; }

int main() {
    auto tup = tuple_from_funs(f, g, h);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << ", " << std::get<1>(tup) << ", " << std::get<2>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/bgV2Ad).

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I do not understand exactly. How is it work? could you give me some reference regarding the line `std::make_tuple(args()...)`?

Comment: `std::make_tuple` is just a function that takes some variadic template arguments and returns a tuple holding all of them. As for the `args()...`, it basically means "apply the call operator on each of the arguments in this parameter pack, and expand it". It's the same as doing `arg0(), arg1(), arg....`.