# Make variadic function which takes arbitary number of void functors

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

[motivated by my previous question : Make variadic function which takes arbitary functors and returns a tuple of each return value of input functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059250/make-variadic-function-which-takes-arbitary-functors-and-returns-a-tuple-of-each)

Now, I want to make a class which just execute each function object which may return void.
To the best of my knowledge, I can make something like,

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class Func>
    void operator()(Func func)
    {
        func();
    }

    template <class First, class... Funcs>
    void operator()(First first, Funcs... funcs)
    {
        first();
        operator()(funcs...);
    }
};
```

This code does the job.
However, I guess there must be much more clever way like the codes by `Nawaz` and `mfontanini` in the above link.

I tried below imitating their code.

```
class A
{
public:
    template <class... Func>
    void operator()(Func func...)
    {
        func()...;
    }
};
```

However, gcc 4.7.2 doesn't compile. Am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
template <class... Func>
void operator()(Func ... func) //corrected the syntax here
{
    sink( (func(),0)... );
}
```

where `sink` is defined as:

```
template<typename ...T> void sink(T...) {}
```

The purpose of `sink` is to eat the value of the expression `(func(),0)` which is just `0` irrespective of what `func()` returns. It will work even if `func()` return type is `void`.

- [Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d8be78d9e671e2efa81ee56cacb53159)

Notice the in the demo above first two functions return something but the third one returns `void`.

If you want the functions to be called from left-to-right, then you can use list-initialization syntax:

```
 int sink[]{func(),0)... };
```

But it unnecessarily creates a *variable*. So I would define `sink` as struct:

```
struct sink
{
     template<typename ...T> 
     sink(T...) {}  //templated constructor!
};
```

With this you can do this:

```
sink { (func(),0)... }; //note the curly-braces now!
```

Updated demo:

- [Online Demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2679b4748a288425ec0d45967aa0ca54)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Sungmin: Posted a demo also!

Comment: The `sink` has a problem, as I explain in my answer and as can be seen from the live example: the functions don't execute in the given order.

Comment: @Xeo: It is `int` in this case, which is not a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Nawaz' answer, you need a certain *context* to perform pack expansion - it can't just be done anywhere. One of those contexts is function arguments, another would be any kind if initialization.

The `sink` function that Nawaz gave is a good starting point, but it has a serious deficiency - you don't have a guaranteed order in which the functors execute. If you want your users to be able to rely on the order they pass to you, you need a context that ensures left-to-right evaluation. Array initialization and list-initialization both fit here.

Using array initialization:

```
template <class... Func>
void operator()(Func func...)
{
    int ignored[] = { (func(),0)... };
    (void)ignored; // silence unused variable warnings
}
```

Using list-initialization:

```
struct swallow{
  template<class... Ignored>
  swallow(Ignored&&...)
};

template <class... Func>
void operator()(Func func...)
{
    swallow{ (func(),0)... }; // create a temporary 'swallow' from all arguments
}
```

The `(func(), 0)` part just executes `func`, discards the return value, if any, and then evaluates to `0`.

Usually, if you want to do this for any functor, regardless of return type, and just throw away the results, you'd write it as `(void(func()), 0)...`. The `void(...)` part swallows whatever return value comes from `func()`, if anything. This is needed because a user is allowed to overload `operator,`, and might decide to do so for his own type and `int` (the type of literal `0`), which would undermine your efforts. However, you can't overload `operator,` with `void` on any side.

Comment: Thank you for pointing our this issue. I love your solution. However, I have a question regarding the way using array initialization. Every time I call the function, I see array is constructed and destructed. Isn't the overhead quite big compared to the way using list-initialization?

Comment: @Sungmin: Since the array is unused, it's highly likely to be completely optimized away. And even then, blasting away 40 or what bytes for 10 functors isn't much. The same goes for the references / values of `swallow`'s constructor, btw.

Comment: @Sungmin, initialization_list also uses array under the hood, you just don't see it.

Comment: @ixSci: So you mean that the initialize-list has the same overhead?

Comment: I can't say for sure, since I'm not compiler dev, but I'd say "Yes" it has the same overhead, but as @Xeo pointed out it will be optimized away anyway. From the standard(8.5.4/5) `An object of type std::initializer_list<E> is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
allocated an array of N elements of type E, where N is the number of elements in the initializer list`

Comment: @ixSci: No, I'm not creating an `initializer_list` here. The initialization *form* is called "list-initialization", but it translates to a direct constructor call.

Comment: @Sungmin: See the comment above.

Comment: @Xeo, I see, I just misinterpreted `list-initialization` term as `initialization_list` and thought that @Sungmin is interested if there would be less overheads with `initialization_list`. Sorry.