# C++11 variadic template unpacking arguments in functor

Tags: templates, c++11, lua, unpack, variadic

I'm messing around with variadic templates and trying to workout a luabinding scheme going. I know they exist but just trying to mess around with new features. I'm working is a VS2013 trial currently. I've created a functor class that is a wrapper around the information I need to call a lua function from the C++ side; However, I can't for the life of me get my template function that is made to push the variables onto the stack to unpack and work. I've tried every example on the net I could find and tried every way they mention how to unpack the values for function templates. I'm obviously missing something. All the examples I noticed took && move references. Is that a requirement?

```
/*
These functions push an item onto the lua stack
*/
template<typename T> inline void lua_push(lua_State* L,T&& t){ static_assert(false,      "Unsupported Type! Cannot set to lua stack"); }
template<> inline void lua_push<lua_CFunction>(lua_State* L,lua_CFunction&& func){      assert(L != nullptr && func != nullptr); lua_pushcfunction(L, func); }
template<> inline void lua_push<double>(lua_State* L,double&& d){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushnumber(L, d); }
template<> inline void lua_push<int>(lua_State* L,int&& i){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushinteger(L, i); }
template<> inline void lua_push<bool>(lua_State* L,bool&& b){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushboolean(L, b); }
template<> inline void lua_push<std::string>(lua_State* L,std::string&& s){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushlstring(L, s.c_str(), s.size()); }
template<> inline void lua_push<const char*>(lua_State* L,const char*&& s){ assert(L != nullptr); lua_pushstring(L, s); }
```

Then I want to unpack it in this class

```
template<typename Return,typename... Args> class LuaFunctor{};
/*
    A Lua function that will return a single value.
*/
template<typename Return,typename... Args> class LuaFunctor<Return(Args...)>
{
private:
    //The lua state the function exists on
    lua_State* m_luaState;
    //Name of the function to be called in lua
    std::string m_FunctionName;
public:
    //Return typedef
    typedef Return return_type;
    //The number of arguments the functor accepts
    static const int arguments = sizeof...(Args);
    //Constructors
    inline LuaFunctor(lua_State* L,const std::string& name) : m_luaState(L), m_FunctionName(name) {}
    inline LuaFunctor(lua_State* L,const char* name) : m_luaState(L), m_FunctionName(name) {}
    //Function call overload that allows the functor to act like a function call of luascript
    inline Return operator()(Args&&... args)
    {
        //Assert that the function name does exist and luaState is pointing to something hopefully meaningful
        assert(m_luaState != nullptr && m_FunctionName.size() != 0);
        //Set the function
        lua_getglobal(m_luaState, m_FunctionName.c_str());
        //Verify Lua function is pushed onto the stack
        assert(lua_isfunction(m_luaState, -1));
        //If arguments exist push them onto the stack
        if (sizeof...(Args) != 0)
        {
                    /*
                      How do I unpack this?????
                      I want to unpack this into multiple functions
                      One for each type of argument.
                    */
            lua_push(m_luaState, std::forward<Args>(args))...; 
        }
        //Call the function that is in lua
        int status = lua_pcall(m_luaState, sizeof...(Args), 1, 0);
        /*
            If there was an error calling the function throw an exception
            TODO: parse the error using luas builtin decode of the error for now just pass it on
            TODO: create lua_exception
        */
        if (status != 0) throw std::exception("Error calling lua function");
        //Return the value request by lua, error checking is built-in to the function to verify type
        return lua_get<Return>(m_luaState);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you add what happens with your above code? Does it compile successfully? Are you sure `lua_push`'s inside `if (sizeof...(Args) != 0)` is getting called?

Comment: No it wasn't compiling. I found a solution though.

`template<typename First, typename... Rest> inline void lua_push(lua_State* L,First first,Rest... rest)
{
 lua_push(L, first);
 lua_push(L, rest...);
}`

this function recursively calls lua_push grabbing the correct type each time. Then I just need to call `lua_push(L,args...);` and no headache.

Comment: [`int swallow[] = {0, (lua_push(L, args), 0)...};`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15062302/500104)

Comment: what you are calling move references is actually perfect forwarding and universal references in that context: related but not the quite the same. If you want tonunderstand what they do, google those terms.

Comment: @xeo order issues there?  I forget.

Comment: @Yakk: Nope, aggregate init is forced left-to-right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the fix. Recursive function calls. Tried all sorts of hacks that I was reading about but this is clean and simple.

```
/*
    These functions push an item onto the lua stack
*/
template<typename First, typename... Rest> inline void lua_push(lua_State* L,First first,Rest... rest)
{
    lua_push(L, first);
    lua_push(L, rest...);
}
template<typename T> inline void lua_push(lua_State* L, T t){ static_assert(false, "Invalid type attemptiing to be pushed onto lua stack!"); }
template<> inline void lua_push<lua_CFunction>(lua_State* L, lua_CFunction func){ assert(L != nullptr && func != nullptr); lua_pushcfunction(L, func); }
template<> inline void lua_push<double>(lua_State* L, double d){assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushnumber(L, d); }
template<> inline void lua_push<int>(lua_State* L, int i){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushinteger(L, i); }
template<> inline void lua_push<bool>(lua_State* L, bool b){ assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushboolean(L, b); }
template<> inline void lua_push<std::string>(lua_State* L, std::string s){assert(L != nullptr);  lua_pushlstring(L, s.c_str(), s.size()); }
template<> inline void lua_push<const char*>(lua_State* L,const char* s){ assert(L != nullptr); lua_pushstring(L, s); }
```

The code works perfectly now.

```
template<typename Return,typename... Args> class LuaFunctor<Return(Args...)>
{
private:
    //The lua state the function exists on
    lua_State* m_luaState;
    //Name of the function to be called in lua
    std::string m_FunctionName;
public:
    //Return typedef
    typedef Return return_type;
    //The number of arguments the functor accepts
    static const int arguments = sizeof...(Args);
    //Constructors
    inline LuaFunctor(lua_State* L,const std::string& name) : m_luaState(L), m_FunctionName(name) {}
    inline LuaFunctor(lua_State* L,const char* name) : m_luaState(L), m_FunctionName(name) {}
    //Function call overload that allows the functor to act like a function call of luascript
    inline Return operator()(Args... args)
    {
        //Assert that the function name does exist and luaState is pointing to something hopefully meaningful
        assert(m_luaState != nullptr && m_FunctionName.size() != 0);
        //Set the function
        lua_getglobal(m_luaState, m_FunctionName.c_str());
        //Verify Lua function is pushed onto the stack
        assert(lua_isfunction(m_luaState, -1));
        //If arguments exist push them onto the stack
        if (sizeof...(Args) != 0) lua_push(m_luaState, args...);
        //Call the function that is in lua
        int status = lua_pcall(m_luaState, sizeof...(Args), 1, 0);
        /*
            If there was an error calling the function throw an exception
            TODO: parse the error using luas builtin decode of the error for now just pass it on
            TODO: create lua_exception
        */
        if (status != 0)
        {
            report_errors(status);
            throw std::exception("Error calling lua function");
        }
        //Return the value request by lua, error checking is built-in to the function to verify type
        return lua_get<Return>(m_luaState);
    }
};
```

Comment: You may remove `template<typename T> inline void lua_push(lua_State* L, T t)`, and use simple non template functions `inline void lua_push(lua_State* L, lua_CFunction func) {/*implementation*/}`. `assert(m_luaState != nullptr && m_FunctionName.size() != 0);` may be moved in constructor... Your `inline` within the class are superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, code could be cleaned a bit and it isn't finished. The assert in the () operator is eventually going to be calling other things and have a smart_prt check for the lua_State, so it's more a place holder then anything for more advanced debug checks. Could get rid of the inlines for sure though.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to change `lua_push` into a bunch of overrides.

Have them return some copy or movable type (`bool` will do, or `struct nothing{};`).

Then:

```
auto sink[]={lua_push(m_luaState, std::forward<Args>(args))...};
```

which calls them all.